# invalid type for template argument

Tags: c++, c++11

What is wrong with my template and how to fix it? This is supposed to remove all items from Qt-ish containers, given the predicate function. The compiler yields error `'std::function': 'T::value_type' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Fty'`

```
template <typename T>
void eraseIf( T &container, std::function<bool(T::value_type)> predicate)
{
    auto it = container.begin();
    while( it != container.end() )
    {
        if( predicate( *it ) )
        {
            it = container.erase( it );
        }
        else
        {
            ++it;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `typename T::value_type`

Comment: @rafix07 Thanks, you are right, it solves the problem. Please make it an answer.

Comment: Yes, it is duplicate. But the trouble with duplicates in this case is that unless you do not know the answer, you do not know it is a duplicate. :)